# Non-recursive Quicksort with Stack

Tags: java, stack, quicksort

I am trying to implement quicksort without recursion using a stack. The sort method is supposed to partition, and store the bounds of the sub-lists as arrays within the stack. The sort method will then loop back and pop one of the sub-lists, and partition that, and push back two more sub-lists. This should go on until the whole array of strings is sorted.

The arrays stored in the stack change for some reason, even though I don't touch the stack (to my knowledge). This derails the sort.

This is the code:

```
public static void qsort (String [] data)
    {               
    Stack stk = new Stack ();
    Integer mid;
    Integer [] bounds = new Integer [2];
    bounds [0] = 0;
    bounds [1] = data.length - 1;
    Integer [] rlist = new Integer [2];
    Integer [] llist = new Integer [2];
    while (!stk.isEmpty())
        {
        System.out.println ("----------");
        bounds = stk.pop();
        stk.print();
        System.out.println ("lb " + bounds[0].intValue() + " rb " + bounds [1].intValue());
        print (data);
        stk.print();

        llist[0] = bounds[0];
        System.out.println ("l0 " + llist[0].intValue()  + "  mid: " + mid.intValue() + "  b0 " + bounds[0].intValue() + "  b1 " + bounds[1].intValue());
        llist[1] = new Integer (mid.intValue()-1);
        System.out.println ("l0 " + llist[0].intValue() + "  l1 " + llist[1].intValue() + "  mid: " + mid.intValue() + "  b0 " + bounds[0].intValue() + "  b1 " + bounds[1].intValue());
        stk.print();
        rlist[0] = new Integer (mid.intValue()+1);
        System.out.println ("l0 " + llist[0].intValue() + "  l1 " + llist[1].intValue() + "  mid: " + mid.intValue() + "  r0 " + rlist[0].intValue());
        rlist[1] = bounds[1];
        System.out.println ("l0 " + llist[0].intValue() + "  l1 " + llist[1].intValue() + "  mid: " + mid.intValue() + "  r0 " + rlist[0].intValue() + " r1 " + rlist[1].intValue());

    if (rlist[1].intValue() > rlist[0].intValue()) 
        {
        stk.push (rlist);
        System.out.println ("pushed right");
        }
    if (llist[1].intValue() > llist[0].intValue()) 
        {
        stk.push (llist);
        System.out.println ("pushed left");
        }
    System.out.println("stksize "+stk.size);
    stk.print();
    }
}
```

I added a bunch of print statements for debugging purposes. For the given input:

```
q
w
e
r
a
t
```

I get this output:

```
----------
---
---
lb 0 rb 5
a
e
q
r
w
t
---
---
l0 0  mid: 2  b0 0  b1 5
l0 0  l1 1  mid: 2  b0 0  b1 5
---
---
l0 0  l1 1  mid: 2  r0 3
l0 0  l1 1  mid: 2  r0 3 r1 5
pushed right
pushed left
stksize 2
---
l 0 r 1
l 3 r 5
---
----------
---
l 3 r 5
---
lb 0 rb 1
a
e
q
r
w
t
---
l 3 r 5
---
l0 0  mid: 0  b0 0  b1 1
l0 0  l1 -1  mid: 0  b0 0  b1 -1
---
l 3 r 5
---
l0 0  l1 -1  mid: 0  r0 1
l0 0  l1 -1  mid: 0  r0 1 r1 -1
stksize 1
---
l 1 r -1
---
----------
---
---
lb 1 rb -1
a
e
q
r
w
t
---
---
l0 1  mid: 1  b0 1  b1 -1
l0 1  l1 0  mid: 1  b0 1  b1 -1
---
---
l0 1  l1 0  mid: 1  r0 2
l0 1  l1 0  mid: 1  r0 2 r1 -1
stksize 0
---
---
a
e
q
r
w
t
```

I separated each iteration by printing "--------". Note that the values stored in the stack are being altered where I am reassigning values for extraneous variables.

Comment: I don't get it. You are trying to sort the String[] array data, but you never compare any alement of data[...] to anything. The only comparison in the loop that takes place is in rlist and llist but these hold indices within the data array.